# Horizontal Collection View with automatic cell size is destroying cells on item reload

Tags: swift, uikit, rx-swift

When I tap on item in collection view cell is loosing size with clumsy animation. Effect on first screenshots. I'm guessing there is something with my stackview inside custom cell but can't figure it out on my own. Stack view has top, right, bottom and left constrain set to superview (contentView)

[image]

[image]

This is hierarchy of collection view structure:

[image]

This is code responsible for selecting and reloading cells. I have array of selected items.

```
filterCollectionView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] index in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        if self.loginViewModel.filtersSelected.contains(index.item) {
            self.loginViewModel.filtersSelected.remove(index.item)
        } else {
            self.loginViewModel.filtersSelected.insert(index.item)
        }
        
        self.filterCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [index])
        
    }).disposed(by: bag)
```

This is code responsible for binding and displaying cells

```
loginViewModel.filters.bind(to: filterCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "FilterCell", cellType: FilterCell.self)) { [weak self] cv, item, cell in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.updateData(icon: UIImage(named: item.image), text: item.text)
            let isSelected = self.loginViewModel.filtersSelected.contains(item.id)
            cell.updateView(isSelected)
        }
        
    }.disposed(by: bag)
```

And this is custom cell

```
class FilterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var filterIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var filterText: UILabel!


    func updateView(_ isSelected: Bool) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .blue : .white
    }

    func updateData(icon: UIImage?, text: String?) {
        filterIcon.image = icon ?? filterIcon.image
        filterText.text = text ?? filterText.text
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough information to understand the problem :)

EDIT:
When I delete DispatchQueue.main it gets even weirder. Tapped cell is collapsing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because of the extra DispatchQueue call within your cell definition. The system is likely pulling the cell size before you update the contents of the cell. I see no reason what that should be there. If your `filters` is emitting on a background thread, then use `.observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)` before the `bind(to:)`.

If that isn't it, then check that the content hugging priority is set to high on the `filterIcon` and `filterText`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I've edited my question (new screenshot). I've tried to set hugging priority to hight both on filterIcon and filterText, even on contentView. Nothing changed. What's more, when I use reloadData() everything works just fine (except I loose offset of collectionView). When I use reloadItems(at:) cells are collapsing but it repairs when I scroll a little bit (one more evidence that it's something with cells refreshing)